# Translate a Variable string in a more complex one in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string that looks like this, containing a variable number of pairs:

```
21.0 2016-04-12 04:06:00, 21.2 2016-04-12 04:09:00, ...
```

It should be translated to this:

```
{"date": VAR1, "value": VAR2}, {"date": VAR3,"value": VAR4},
```

Where the variables are filled in like this:

```
VAR2 = 21.0
VAR1 = 2016-04-12 04:06:00
...
```

Is there an efficient way to do this with PHP?

Comment: is the output is JSON ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `explode` your string with comma and loop through the values, and again `explode` the `$value` using  space with limit of 2.

Then simply append output in a variable.

```
$str = "21.0 2016-04-12 04:06:00, 21.2 2016-04-12 04:09:00";
$output = '';
foreach(explode(',', $str) as $key => $value) {
    $sp = explode(' ', trim($value), 2);
    $output .= ',{"date": ' . $sp[1] . ', "value": ' . $sp[0] . '}';
}
$output = empty($output) ? '' : substr($output, 1);
echo $output;
```

Example: https://eval.in/581825

Comment: It's better to use json_encode instead, otherwise special characters in input string can make the resulting json invalid

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo that's not a valid json what op shown, I must better get clarified from op

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what I was looking for. 

The output is used in JavaScript.